# How to Enter command in search form?

Tags: powershell

i have created a powershell to login to a website.
after the login i get the form where i a perform a search for ean-code. but the form needs and enter to start the search

this is the code of the website

```
<form method="get" action="/assortiment/zoeken/"><input type="text" name="q" id="searchfield" value="5410376123008" placeholder="zoekwoord of artikel"/><input type="submit" id="searchbutton" value="" /></form>
```

id="searchbutton" is the value where an ENTER is needed

```
$c = $host.UI.PromptForCredential('Your Credentials', 'Enter Credentials', '', '')
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://b2b.odin.nl/registratie/login/' -SessionVariable my_session
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields['cid'] = $c.UserName
$form.fields['psw'] = $c.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$resultweb = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ('https://b2b.odin.nl' + $form.Action) -WebSession $my_session -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
$ean = "5410376123008"

$formweb = $resultweb.Forms[0]
$formweb.fields['searchfield'] = $ean
$formweb.fields['searchbutton'] = {ENTER}

$resultformweb = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ('https://b2b.odin.nl' + $formweb.Action + "?q=") -WebSession $my_session -Method POST -Body $formweb.Fields
```

how to enter ?

Answer (score 0):

POST.

You don't really need to click enter. What you need to do is perform a post request with the "$ean". You can see this request being performed by your browser when you click "enter" manually. That is what you want to mimic.

It will probably look something like:

```
iwr http://example.org/post `
-Method 'POST' `
-Body @{ 'searchfield' = 'something'}
```

[This](https://davidhamann.de/2019/04/12/powershell-invoke-webrequest-by-example/) is a good introduction to http requests. You could skip to the section about POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is go to this page, open up Chrome or EdgeDev tool and then fill out the search box.

Then open the network pane and see which request happens.  It will be either a Put or a POST request (almost definitely a `POST`), and you can then right-click the request and chose 'Copy as PowerShell'.

Then you paste it into PowerShell and see how it worked!

If you want some more examples, I wrote a post about it [here with pictures.](https://foxdeploy.com/2018/04/02/faster-web-cmdlet-design-with-chrome-65/)

Answer (score 0):

thnx

i found out that they referred to different link

```
$TEST = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ('https://b2b.odin.nl/assortiment/zoeken/?q=' + $ean) -WebSession $my_session
$TEST.Links
```

now it's working

i overlooked it

it's solved